# In The LEGO Batman Movie, who are the agent looking villains?

Tags: dc, character-identification, lego, the-lego-batman-movie, lego-cinematic-universe

In the movie, there are some secret agent type villains that all appear to be identical to one another. They also repeat everything one of them says, like an echo. They remind me of Agents from The Matrix, but LEGO has no prior relationship with that property so I'm not certain. As noted in comments, The Matrix is a WB property, so it *could* be them. However, most of the other villains we see have already had appearances in other LEGO media, namely The LEGO Dimensions video game and related sets.

All the articles I've found (so far) only *speculate* that they're Agents, but I've not seen any confirmation. Unfortunately, I didn't get to check the end credits to see if they were named there.

Who are these bad guys, and what property are they from?

Comment: Anything owned by WB is fair game I think.

Comment: I'd assumed they were agents since The Matrix is also a WB property.  Similarly, Harry Potter, King Kong: Skull Island, and Wizard of Oz are also movies owned by WB.  Though at the same time there are still other franchises featured that are not owned by WB, like Doctor Who and Lord of the Rings (there are already licensing deals for LoTR with WB though), so I could be wrong in my assumption.

Comment: @kai - Warner Bros. already have a licensing agreement in place with the BBC over the use of the Daleks; http://warner-bros-characters.wikia.com/wiki/The_Daleks, and with LOTR (http://www.wbshop.com/category/wbshop_brands/the+lord+of+the+rings+lotr.do)

Comment: Great question. In a similar vein, I'm trying to remember the name of a film where if a bus goes below a certain speed it blows up. I think there was a sequel with a boat that couldn't go below a certain speed either, but no idea what the films were called.

Comment: @Peter - You're thinking of "[The bus that couldn't slow down](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIrIvKKT_nk)"

Comment: @valorum Also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4uOX_hbkAMc :D

Comment: @Valorum - The use of the Daleks in Looney Tunes was quasi-unauthorized. WB asked the BBC, and it "gave permission" which it didn't technically have - the Daleks are controlled by the Terry Nation estate. There were quite a few feathers ruffled as a result of that, so much so that the estate considered refusing permission to use them on the new Doctor Who series. Steve Martin (who had requested them in the first place) wrote a contrite letter of apology to the estate, and they relented.

Comment: @Valorum (2/2) The fact that the Daleks are referred to as "British Robots", and there is no mention of their creator in the credits (that I noticed), I am of the opinion that their use was "grandfathered in" from an existing permission given (perhaps the fact they can be used in the Lego Dimension game), and they just played cute with the name. I'm hoping they don't get themselves in a similar situation with using them in any future Doctor Who - related projects.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Those were [Agents Smith(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_Smith) from the Matrix franchise.

[image: Lego Agents Smith above Matrix Agents Smith below]

> **Q. You even included the Gremlins.**
>
> *Yeah, Gremlins **and Agent Smith**. And Warner Bros. bought the MGM
> library, so they’ve got the Wicked Witch. But also, the one reason why
> I can’t do Kathy Bates or Moriarty is less about the rights holders
> and more about the fact that it would be hard to sell who that
> character is easily. I’d already crammed it with a bunch of Rogues
> Galleries and we’ve got a lot of main characters and a lot of
> characters that we want to hear more from, so at a certain point it
> became like, okay, how many obscure characters can we fit in and
> people understand who they are. At one point I had HAL from 2001 in
> there.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Director Chris McKay Shares The Secrets Behind ‘The LEGO Batman Movie’](https://uproxx.com/movies/the-lego-batman-movie-chris-mckay/)</sup></sub>

and

> *I just wanted to throw as many in there that I possibly could. There was ones that I wanted to do, like maybe put Moriarty in there from Sherlock Holmes, but it's just a hard read. Some of them are just so visual that you immediately get who they are or at the very least that they're a bad guy. **The Agent Smith is probably the closest thing to Moriarty, but it's just such a distinct performance thing and a visual look to it. We could do sort of the thing with one guy turning into three of them that even if you don't know those movies, you just sort of get it.***
>
> <sub><sup>[The LRM Interview with LEGO Batman Movie Director Chris McKay](https://web.archive.org/web/20170708144553/http://lrmonline.com/news/the-lrm-interview-with-lego-batman-movie-director-chris-mckay)</sup></sub>

Comment: Do I want to know how you got that screengrab?

Comment: Is it _Agent**s**_ or _Smith**s**_? Because they're identical in the movie (and that picture), that interview says only Smith, and they also repeated one another.

Comment: @CreationEdge - You do not.

Comment: I also assumed they were multiple Smiths rather than multiple Agents because they kept repeating/echoing each other.

Comment: @Ixrec - Further research leads me to that conclusion as well.

Comment: The second quote sinches it.